# How to let xUnit runner only execute tests in specific classes?

Tags: msbuild, xunit, xunit.net

In my csproj file I've defined a test target which is used to execute xunit tests in a specified DLL:

```
<UsingTask AssemblyFile="..\packages\xunit.1.9.2\lib\net20\xunit.runner.msbuild.dll"     TaskName="Xunit.Runner.MSBuild.xunit" />
  <Target Name="Test">
    <xunit Assembly="bin\Debug\My.Project.dll" />
</Target>
```

This works fine, however I would like to be able to specify that only tests in certain classes should be executed. Is this possible?

Answer (score 10):

You could switch out the `xunit` task for an `Exec` task and run the XUnit console runner, `xunit.console.clr4.exe`. This has command line options for specifying 'traits' to run. These are name value pairs that can be assigned to tests by using the `TraitAttribute`:

```
    [Trait("TraitName", "TraitValue")]
    public void MyTest(){ /*..*/ }
```

From the usage test for the console runner:

`Valid 
  /trait "name=value"    : only run tests with matching name/value traits
                         : if specified more than once, acts as an OR operation
  /-trait "name=value"   : do not run tests with matching name/value traits
                         : if specified more than once, acts as an AND operation`

Comment: You also use -method parameters with a full method name eg:    

    `xunit.console.clr4.exe -method Namespace.ClassName.MethodName`

Comment: @aguafrommars, with V2 released, it's even easier: `xunit.console.exe -class 'Namespace.ClassName'`.